# Splitting strictly using perl

Tags: perl, split

In the below code, I am trying to split between two numbers. The splitting is not functioning correctly. For eg: when I split between 0 and 1, the split also occurs in between digits of 10 and 11.

Can some one help me in this?

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $j= "0,2,3,6,5,1,4,7,8,12,11,10,9";
    my $k=1; my $k1=0,;
    my @ar=split(/($k|$k1)/,$j);

    print join(";",@ar);

    Expected result:0;2,3,6,5;1;4,7,8,12,11,10,9
    Above code result: 0;,2,3,6,5,;1;,4,7,8,;1;2,;1;1;,;1;0;,9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't want to split on 0 or 1, you want to split on a commas next to the number `0` or `1`.

```
split /(?<!\d)(?:0|1)\K,|,(?=(?:0|1)(?!\d))/
```

Comment: I put your code in this way in the program my $k=0;my $k1=1;
my $j= "0,2,3,6,5,1,4,7,8,12,11,10,9";
@ar =~ split /(?<!\d)(?:0|1)\K,|,(?=(?:0|1)(?!\d))/;
print join(";",@ar); I am unable to display?

Comment: Sorry I used this, @ar =~ split(/(?<!\d)(?:0|1)\K,|,(?=(?:0|1)(?!\d))/,$j); print join(";",@ar); Could not display any info

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
split /(\b$k\b|\b$k1\b)/, $j
```

`\b` is the zero width word boundary delimiter.

Comment: @ikegami But it does not split the 11 and the 10, which is what you asked about. Note that split returns you empty elements if you keep the separator and it matches at the beginning / end. This is by design. I also suggest you deal with the commas differently. Maybe you could start with `split /,/, $j` and go from there.